# How can I create a database with marker information to retrieve in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter, folium

How and where to create database with information about your markers and then retrieve this info from your database by means of code?

Hello.I want to create many markers on my map but it is very long to create all of these and,consequently, I found that you can create database and write all the info about your markers there in and after this to load this info in your jupyter. After that, your map fill out with markers. How to do this?

I will be grateful

Comment: For easy access and editing you can manage your data in excel. In your jupyter notebook you can import this data in a pandas DataFrame and then create a map with folium. Lookup some tutorials with this key points and you will find a solution!

Comment: Hello. Thank you for explanation. Can you recommend any tutorials on this topic? I cant find

Comment: I can not believe you really looked for it. Use your preferred search engine and search for example ```excel import pandas tutorial``` ... there are 3 million hits, thats not that difficult